# Wobbly wheel/hub even when I tightened the cones

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, wheels, shimano, repair

The wheel has a sideways wobble eminating from the hub. I tried adjusting the cones to the point its too tight but the wobble continues. Upon closer inspection there is play in the point where the freewheel connects to the hub. Its a 2006 shimano deore MTB hub. How to fix?

Comment: You might "just" need to true the wheel. But this may be a non-trivial task and you may want to involve an lbs.

Comment: 'Play' - does it move from side to side when the wheel is stationary, or does it wobble when the wheel spins?   The Freewheel screws on. If there is play in the hub/freewheel connection, its loose and the hub is probably stuffed if its been ridden that way.  Remove the freewheel (need to remove axle and needs a 10mm hex key) and check the threads.

Comment: Stationary. The axle is solidly in place at off side of the wheel but on the drive side I can feel the slack and move the axle with my fingers. And the whole freewheel moves with it and I can see the freewheel / hub connection expand

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue on my bike recently. It could be a bent axle, damage on the inside of the hub, or both. If the axle is true, you will need to replace the hub or a whole new wheel. Good news, a new MTB wheel is relatively cheap, on the order of about $50-60.

Comment: Sounds like what happenend to me here - http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/37769/what-caused-play-in-my-freehub

Comment: That could be the case. Mine was on a freewheel and I generally wrench on my old busted bikes to keep me rolling as cheaply as possible, so I don't have any hands-on experience with freehub bearings yet.

Answer (score 0):

If its the free-hub body you could just try replacing that! It should separate from the wheel with a large allen key (10mm) once you remove the axle and bearings. (price approx €20). If there's extreme play in it you would most likely get the symptoms you describe.

Comment: Simply throwing money at problems can be a good solution, but in this case more investigation is required.  It might be an older style freewheel instead of a freehub.